# Hiding access token from client side

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed the [tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/2legged/nodejs) to generate and use access tokens. Now, i get it just fine and put it in the options argument of the Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer.
My issue is that, i got to call the route using jQuery and as such, the response is visible from the network tab in devtools.
Is there a way to completely hide it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try with the mechanism of token proxy which is described at:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/proxying-forge-viewer
or
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy

Comment: thanks, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: glad it helps. When you have  little chance, could you accept it as answer? Thank you.